# How to maintain the inassociativity in MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, fortran

I have a somewhat simple question but I couldn't reproduce the correct answer when transcription a Fortran-90 code to MATLAB.

The following MATLAB code is initialized using an integer `i0 = 842739021913`. This is a part of Fortran-90 code consist of a more general integer random number generator routine.

```
i0 = 842739021913 ; 
function x_tdrand = tdrand
    ia = int32(513) ; ib = int32(29741096258473) ; it = int32(140737488355328) ; 
    t = 1.40737488355328e14 ; 
    i0 = ia*i0+ib ; 
    i0 = i0-(i0/it)*it ; 
    x_tdrand = i0/t ;     
end
```

The second calculation of `i0` (i.e., `i0=i0-(i0/it)*it`) should give `i0=39853749433858` in Fortran-90 (see below) but using MATLAB i obviously get zero.
Appreciate any of your advice of how to reproduce the Fortran code correctly.

```
SUBROUTINE TDRAND(X)
  USE module_GENERAL, ONLY: I0
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER(8) :: IA, IB, IT
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: X, T

  DATA IA, IB, IT /513, 29741096258473, 140737488355328/
  DATA T /1.40737488355328D14/

  I0=IA*I0+IB
  I0=I0-(I0/IT)*IT
  X=DBLE(I0)/T

  RETURN
  END SUBROUTINE TDRAND
```

Comment: `int32` is probably too small for your purposes, after all your Fortran integers are (probably) 64-bit.  Try `int64`.  Possibly investigate `idivide` too.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - Yes the int64 did the trick. Thank you !

Comment: little warning those large literals should have a `_8` in the fortran code.

Comment: @agentp - Thanks for the note. Care to elaborate a little bit ? Should I defined the large numbers more carefully ?

Comment: Yes, as `29741096258473_8`, although a named constant would be better than just literal 8.